# UISearchbar under a UINavigationBar within a UITableViewController not in the header

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I am trying to add a UISearchBar with a UIButton that has a custom image.  I want the UISearchBar to be locked to the Navigation bar, but still show both the SearchBar and the Navigation Bar.  I don't want the SearchBar as the Headerview for the TableView within the UITableView controller.  I have tried creating a UIToolBar to hold the custom button and flexible space button.  Then adding that Toolbar and the Searchbar to self.view and self.navigationController.view.  Then as an extension to my initial issue, I was wondering if I could set the frame of self.tableView manually to accomodate the new size of the space available after adding the Searchbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should check out `UISearchDisplayController` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as it might be very close to what you have in mind. I also strongly recommend checking out the free [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com) framework. The framework automatically provides all the search and table view filtering functionality which should save you a lot of time.

Comment: Instead of trying to do this programmatically, I just created a nib for this ViewController and accomplished it that way.  I would still like to know if this is possible.